# Must my laptop connect to internet during installation?

Tags: 10.10, installation

I am only able to use wireless network while installing Ubuntu right now.

The installer says for best results, ensure the computer is connected to the internet. I was wondering if not connected to internet, will there be a problem? Is there some remedy after installation without connection to internet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not have to have the computer connected to the Internet at that time because you can do your updates right after your installation. It just makes things faster for you when you have it finally up and running.

Comment: Language packs are downloaded later on (when connection is available).
When you boot up your new ubuntu system you are asked if you want to install missing language and localization packages...